# What is the difference between linear operator in a pair of basis and a linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $e_1,...,e_n$ be a basis in $X$ and $f_1,...,f_m$ basis in $Y$. From the following image the matrix $A$ is a linear operator in a pair of basis.

[image]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a linear map $A$, the lines
$$
A(e_1) = a_{11}f_1 + a_{21}f_2 + \cdots + a_{m1}f_m\\
A(e_2) = a_{12}f_1 + a_{22}f_2 + \cdots + a_{m2}f_m\\
\vdots\\
A(e_n) = a_{1n}f_1 + a_{2n}f_2 + \cdots + a_{mn}f_m
$$
completely define what the linear map $A$ does to any vector in $X$, as the $e_n$ are a basis for $X$. Which is to say, if you know it's written in this form, and you know that we're using the $e_i$ basis for $X$ and the $f_j$ basis for $Y$, then the numbers $a_{ij}$ that appear in those lines completely determine what the linear map $A$ does to any vector in $X$.

So we put those numbers $a_{ij}$ in a neat little table, and we call such a table a "matrix". And since this particular linear map is called $A$, and the matrix is constructed directly from the linear map, we often give the matrix the name $A$ as well.

And the entire act of taking a vector $v\in X$, write it out as a linear combination of the $e_i$, and then using the $a_{ij}$ as described in the formula above to find $A(v)$ expressed as a linear combination of the $f_j$'s, we call matrix-vector multiplication, and we write it $Av$.

Certainly, we can go in the reverse as well: Given any $m\times n$ matrix of numbers, we can by this rule interpret that matrix as a linear map.

So what this paragraph does is, it explains the connections between linear maps and matrices: Given two vector spaces, $X$ of dimension $n$ and $Y$ of dimension $m$, each with a chosen basis, there is always a nice correspondence between the set of $m\times n$ matrices and the set of linear maps $X\to Y$.

Comment: Can you explain me this: Let i, j be the first basis and a = 2i + j, b = -1i +j the second basis. If we now define the linear operator to be A(i) = a and A(j) = b the matrix A is then {{1,0},{0,1}. What does this matrix now represent? In fact the matrix will be the same no matter what the second basis is. Is this maybe not the way you are supposed to define A? I don't understand what's the goal here.

Comment: @ToTheSpace2 If you keep $A(i) = a, A(j)=b$, but change what $a$ and $b$ are, then you will necessarily also change the linear map $A$. And you will change it in such a way that it will exactly seem to cancel out the changes to the $a, b$ basis, and the matrix representation of $A$ ends up looking the same in the end. Usually, we don't have two bases on the same space and at the same time have a linear map from that space to itself, wanting to express the input in one base and the output in another base. But that is what you have here.

Comment: Are we using the same symbol A for two different matrices?
A(e) is not the same as A defined by $a_{ij}$ coefficients?

Comment: @ToTheSpace2 If you have two two-dimensional spaces $X$ and $Y$, and you have a basis $i, j$ on one and $a, b$ on the other, and you have a linear map $A:X\to Y$ such that $A(i) = a, A(j) = b$, then $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ will be the matrix representation for this map. If you now change what $a$ and $b$ are, but keep $A(i) = a, A(j) = b$, then you must necessarily have changed the map $A$ as well. If you want to keep the name $a$ and $b$ for the new basis vectors, and the name $A$ for the new linear map, then you're bound to encounter confusion.

Comment: And yes, I said two _different_ spaces $X, Y$, but there is nothing stopping them from being the same space, and if they happen to be the same space, then yes you could express $a$ and $b$ as linear combinations of $i$ and $j$. But that is not really relevant to what's going on here. Nothing is stopping it from happening, but it's not in any mathematically significant way a special case. It's just rare, and makes for some additional mental challenges in keeping everything straight.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a linear operator $A : X \to Y$.  To get a matrix that represents the operator, we need to use bases for the spaces.
If $e_1,\dots, e_n$ is a basis for $X$ and $f_1, \dots, f_m$ is a basis for $Y$, then we do this:
For each $j = 1, \dots n$, the image $A(e_j)$ is a vector in $Y$, so it has an expansion in terms of $f_1,\dots, f_m$.  Let that expansion be
$$
A(e_j) = a_{1j}f_1+\dots + a_{mj}f_m
$$
The matrix corresponding to $A$ is then the matrix of all these coefficients.  Column $j$ of the matrix corresponds to $A(e_j)$, the entry in row $i$ is $a_{ij}$; that is the coefficient of $f_i$ in the expansion of $A(e_j)$.

Comment: What do you mean "start with a linear operator"? How do I know what effect will that linear operator have? If i want a certain transformation, how do I know what operator should I start with? Do I define the operator first with respect to the standard basis or what?

Comment: This only tells you how a linear operator corresponds to a matrix.  It does not tell you where that linear operator came from.  Perhaps that text has some examples for this.